# old listviews being evaluated

Tags: django, python-3.4

I am using windows 10, django 1.11 python 3.4
`
http://127.0.0.1:8000/venues/16165/

in url.py

```
url(r'^venues/(?P<pk>\w+)/$', VenueDetailView.as_view()),
```

in views.py

```
class VenueDetailView(ListView):
#     template_name = 'venues_list.html'
    queryset = TestVenue.objects.all()
```

when I enter the url I get

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/venues/
Using the URLconf defined in bioskop.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
^admin/
^$
^venues/(?P<pk>\w+)/$
^about/$
^contact/$
The current path, venues/, didn't match any of these.
```

if i enter http://127.0.0.1:8000/venues/asdlkfj;akdjf

I get a valid web page from an old listview.

I've tried clearing cache and using a different browser.

I've tried rebooting and restarting server

```
python -B manage.py runserver
```

I'm at a loss why it keeps using old code to render pages.

Answer (score 0):

You are inheriting your view from `ListView`. You may need to change that to `DetailView`.

```
class VenueDetailView(DetailView):
```

Also, you need to change your url,

```
url(r'^venues/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', VenueDetailView.as_view()),
```

`\w+` --> `\d+`

`\w` matches any alphanumeric characters and underscore, ie set [a-zA-Z0-9_].

`\d` matches only digits.

Answer (score 0):

The console command to clear sessions helped resolve the issue for me. Thanks for the help.

```
python manage.py clearsessions
```